# How to get server URL when running on Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, restify

I use [restify](http://mcavage.me/node-restify/) to create a node API that is deployed to Elastic Beanstalk.

```
var server = restify.createServer({ name: 'My API' });

server.listen(process.env.PORT || 1704, function() {
  console.log('%s listening at %s', server.name, server.url);
});
```

When running locally, I see:

> My API listening at http://0.0.0.0:1704

But, when running on Elastic Beanstalk, the logs show:

> My API listening at http://0.0.0.0:8081

Why is that?

Why `server.url` isn't `http://my-api.elasticbeanstalk.com`?

How could I get the real URL (something like `http://my-api.elasticbeanstalk.com`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

elastic beanstalk node applications are configured to run on 8081 internally. You can see it in `node.conf`:

```
upstream nodejs {
    server 127.0.0.1:8081;
    keepalive 256;
}
```

Now 8081, is just the internal port. If you examine this conf file you'll see that the external port is actually 8080, which you're ELB will point with port 80. I hope it's not too confusing :)
As for your env URL, you can issue the `eb status` command from your desktop to see the CNAME. It's also written in the EB web console.

Comment: I need to know the full URL in the node app itself to be able to construct the response header (e.g. `Location: http://my-api.elasticbeanstalk.com/my-resource`). `req.url` gives me the `/my-resource` bit, but I'm not sure how to get the `http://my-api.elasticbeanstalk.com` bit. Any ideas?

Comment: do you mean programatically? I believe there's an environment variable for "my-api" name, and you can append to that "elasticbeanstalk.com". Check out EB_* env vars.

Comment: Apparently, there is no environment variable that can give me the `my-api` bit. [Here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1893981/Screenshots/lh71.png) is a list of all environment variables. Any other ideas where I could get it from?

Comment: I guess the only option is to add it manually and then get it in the server. you can use the `eb setenv` command from your desktop and then it should appear as a variable in the instance to come.

Comment: I was hoping to get the `my-api` bit dynamically, without explicitely setting it. I ended up doing: `'http://' + req.headers.host`